# Response as a CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, cherrypy

I have the following cherrypy function. The function suppose the response with a CSV file. However, It doesn't works, and i get the following response: `Something went wrong here List(UnacceptedResponseContentTypeRejection(WrappedArray(text/csv)))`.

```
@cherrypy.expose
def myFunction(self, id, a):
    url = "clusters/downAsCSV?id=" + id + "&a=" + a + "&csv=true"
    htmlText = self.general_url(url)
    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
    return htmlText
```

When i paste the same  URL into the browser it does works and the CSV been downloaded into the client.

What could be the reason?

Comment: What exactly is happening here? If you are getting a downloaded CSV then it should be correct...

Comment: You need to work on this question it is very unclear what the problem is and what you need help with

Comment: @PyNEwbie I've just edited the question. Is it clear now?

Comment: Still not sure but I think according to this image http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/advanced.html (check in the middle of the page) you are doing things out of order

Comment: Can you add the full error traceback? How are you deploying the cherrypy application? I'm pretty sure cherrypy is not generating this error `List(UnacceptedResponseContentTypeRejection(WrappedArray(text/csv)))`.